# search result issue in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have search box which is work and show data with pagination but when i search for example for word `sample` which i have 3 posts with that title in first page of results I'm getting results like this:

https://ibb.co/hGGxwQ

But when i go to second page everything changes!

https://ibb.co/eZJMO5

This is my `searchcontroller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $countTodayOrders = Post::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->count();
        $yesterday_posts = Post::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)')->count();
        $weekly_posts = Post::whereBetween( 'updated_at', [Carbon::today()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::today()->endOfWeek()] )->count();
        $monthy_posts = Post::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?', Carbon::today()->month)->count();



        $q = Input::get('q');

        $posts = Post::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('body','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->paginate('2');
        $resultcount = Post::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('slug','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->count();
            return view('theme.search', compact('posts', 'resultcount', 'countTodayOrders', 'yesterday_posts', 'weekly_posts', 'monthy_posts', 'q'));
    }
}
```

This is my `search.Blade`

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('title')
Search results
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-9 technology-left">
             <div class="tc-ch wow fadeInDown"  data-wow-duration=".8s" data-wow-delay=".2s">

                    <h2> Here is <b> {{ $resultcount }} </b> result for your query.</h2>
                    <hr/>

                <!-- panel group -->
                <div class="row form-group">
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-image hide-panel-body">
                                <img src="{{ url('/storage') }}/{{ $post->image }}" class="img-responsive panel-image-preview" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <h4>{{ $post->title }}</h4>
                                <p>{{ substr(strip_tags($post->body), 0, 50) }}{{ strlen(strip_tags($post->body)) > 50 ? "..." : "" }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer text-center">

                                <a href="{{ url('blog/'.$post->slug) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <!-- panel group -->



                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        {!! $posts->links() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

My `route`

```
Route::any('/search', ['uses' => 'SearchController@index', 'as' => 'search.index']);
```

My search box

```
<!-- search box -->
                            <form action="/search" method="post" role="search">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- search box -->
```

Why is that?

Comment: please post a screenshot of your database

Comment: why..........?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably with your `q` parameter not getting passed in the page links.

Just add it In your controller like this:

```
$q = Input::get('q');
$posts = null;
if($q) {
    $posts =  Post::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere('body','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
        ->paginate(2)
        ->appends('q', $q);
}
```

In your blade you should add an if statement to check if there are any posts

```
@if($posts and $posts->count())
    // show posts
@else
    // show a nothing found message
@endif
```

Comment: @RobertNicjoo where did you put it?? Add that line right after you declare `$posts = Post:: ...`

Comment: ok, seems working! but also when i just go to url/search will return me posts just as main page without anything being searched. why is that?

Comment: @RobertNicjoo I've edited my answer. 
Please accept the answer and give it a +1 if it was helpful.